# No se muestran productos de Amazon en el sitio

Tags: wordpress, amazon

buen día

A ver si me pueden ayudar. Me cree una cuenta de afiliados de Amazon para vender productos, pero, no logro que se vean en el sitio. Intente agregar estos links mediante Iframes y con plugins pero no funcionan, no se ven los productos o se quedan "cargando"... pregunte a Hostinger (el hosting) y me comentan que no hay restricciones o bloqueos por su parte.

Probé hacerlo en los 2 ambientes, Staging y Producción directamente y nada.

Este es el Iframe que entrega Amazon para publicarlo dentro de un bloque HTML en Wordpress.

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-popups allow-scripts 
allow-modals allow-forms allow-same-origin" 
style="width:120px;height:240px;" marginwidth="0" 
marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
src="//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&OneJS=1&Operation=GetAdHtml&MarketPlace=US&source=ss&ref=as_ss_li_til&ad_type=product_link&tracking_id=almoplabs22-20&language=es_US&marketplace=amazon&region=US&placement=B082XKFYLJ&asins=B082XKFYLJ&linkId=ca201a538539dfc78dc1f52075fc60f6&show_border=true&link_opens_in_new_window=true">
</iframe>
```

Por favor su ayuda si alguien tiene una pista de que podría estar haciendo mal, este es la página en construcción donde quiero agregar el link del producto https://almohadita.com/almohada-antireflujo/almohada-antireflujo-kebeddy/

Muy agradecido

Comment: Seguro que ese es el widget tal cual? el atributo `src` del iframe está raro, le falta protocolo a esa URL `src="//ws-na.amazon...` y creería queestá buscando un recurso local

Comment: Estimado, si así es como Amazon entrega el Iframe. Acabo de encontrar cual es el problema que tengo, olvide mirar la consola antes de escribir aquí, el por qué no se ven los productos es porque AdBloque estaba haciendo su trabajo, lo apague y pude ver todo... Agradezco mucho tu comentario y veré el SRC del Iframe. Un barazo!